# Singleton Dialog pattern

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, singleton

I have an application which has a dialog box for user input. I want this dialog to only be allowed to be opened once at any given time. Normally I would achieve this via a modal dialog, but I need the user to be able to interact with the parent form while the dialog is open. I tried to achieve this via some code like this:

```
    private static Boolean dialogShown = false;
    public Dialog()
    {
            if (!dialogShown )
            {
                dialogShown = true;
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Close();
            }
    }

    private void Dialog_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            dialogShown = false;
    }
```

The problem with this is that it is possible for the code which constructs this form IE

```
    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.Show();
    }
```

to throw an exception when attempting to show a form that has already been closed. It doesn't happen all of the time, but is easily repeatable. So the question is, what is the correct approach to doing this, because my mutex isn't reliable here.

I've seen a few other similar questions on here but in most cases there were outright better solutions to the use case than a dialog. In this case, it must be a non modal singleton dialog.

-Edit, I should not have used the Singleton, because its causing some confusion. There is a subtle distinction I suppose in that Im only worried about there being a single instance of this dialog open at any given time, and am not concerned with it being the same instance each time. I also should not have used the variable name Visible, because that too was misleading. I edited the code to avoid that. Apologies for the misleading post...

Comment: Why does it _have to be a singleton dialog_? What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Its user input for a lookup value. its only appropriate for there to be a single dialog open at once. It wont cause any runtime issues for there to be multiple dialogs, but its easy for the user to accidentally open multiple instances of the form, and I want to prevent that.

Comment: Plus why are you using locking? Dialogs can only be shown on the UI thread, anyway. Locking doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: If you reuse the dialog, you'll keep the user's last input.  Do you want that?

Comment: I was unaware of the dialogs only being shown on the UI thread. I was afraid that if the user was fast enough, there could be contention over the mutex.

Comment: @MarkW What mutex? Your code sample has no mutex. If your application is multithreaded, you have to make sure that you marshal all UI calls to the UI thread through `BeginInvoke` / `Invoke`. You must also create all controls on the UI thread.

Comment: @xxbbcc I suppose you could argue the the accuracy of the word mutex in this case, but ultimately Visible is supposed to serve as one, in the same way that a port can serve as a mutex for concurrent applications. The private Visible boolean was meant to allow the constructor to detect if some other instance of this class is currently being shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Close()` will dispose your dialog, preventing you from reusing it.
Call `Hide()` instead.

Some other notes:

- You don't need your event handler
- WinForms is strictly single-threaded; you don't need any of your locks
- None of the logic in your constructor makes sense.

Comment: This worked out well, and made the form an actual singleton. And you were 100% right, I didnt need the event handler, or the locks, and my constructor is now empty. Thanks @SLaks